# Finding the latest file in each subdirectory

Tags: python

I have the a similar folder structure for which I need to pull the latest .jpg from each subdirectory:

```
+ C:\\myfiles
    + parentdir1
        +  subdir1
            + somename1.jpg
            + somename2.jpg
            + ...
        + subdir2
            + somename3.jpg
            + somename4.jpg
            + ...
        + ...
    + parentdir2
        +  subdir1
            + somename5.jpg
            + somename6.jpg
            + ...
        + subdir2
            + somename7.jpg
            + somename8.jpg
            + ...
        + ...
    + parentdir3
        +  subdir1
            + somename9.jpg
            + somename10.jpg
            + ...
        + subdir2
            + somename11.jpg
            + somename12.jpg
            + ...
        + ...
    + ...
```

I don't know any of the names of the folders or files but I need to access the last 2 .jpg files in each subdir.

For the sake of making this simple, let's just assume I need to print the last 2 files created in the subdir.

I wrote a script that will search all subdir's in a given parentdir, but I actually need to go iterate through all parentdir's as well

```
import os

path = 'C:\\myfiles'
filelist = []

for i in range(len(os.listdir(path))):
    subpath = path + '\\' + os.listdir(path)[i]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(subpath):
        for file in os.listdir(subpath):
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        sorted_filelist = sorted(filelist, key=os.path.getctime)
        print('the latest jpg file in ' + root + ' is:  ' + sorted_filelist[-1])
        print('the 2nd last jpg file in ' + root + ' is:  ' + sorted_filelist[-2])
    filelist.clear()
```

Comment: By the "last 2", do you mean with respect to their alphabetical filenames, creation dates, modification dates, or what?

Comment: I’m looking for the last 2 sorted by Creation date

Comment: You can get the last two items in a list with `sorted_filelist[-2:]`.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but I need to get to the parent directories and my code example is only getting to sub directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. Note that I sort the files by their last modification times, rather than their creation time because I think that's the way to determine which are "most recent".

```
import glob
import os

N_MOST_RECENT = 2
path = 'C:\\myfiles'

for entry in os.listdir(path):
    subpath = os.path.join(path, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(subpath):
        for subentry in os.listdir(subpath):
            subentrypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(subpath, subentry))
            if os.path.isdir(subentrypath):
                jpg_files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(subentrypath, '*.jpg'))
                sorted_filenames = sorted(jpg_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
                # Create list of filenames of the N most recent files.
                most_recent = [os.path.split(name)[-1] # Extract filename from path.
                                    for name in sorted_filenames[-N_MOST_RECENT:]]
                print(f'{N_MOST_RECENT} most recent .jpg files in "{subentrypath}":\n'
                      f'  {most_recent}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the parent directory, and then through all the sub-directories, using os.listdir().

```
import os

parent_dir = 'path/to/parent/dir'
for subdir in os.listdir(parent_dir):
    if not os.path.isdir(subdir):
        continue
    sorted_filelist = sorted(
        [os.path.join(parent_dir, subdir, f) for f in os.listdir(subdir)
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.jpg'],
        key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)
    print(sorted_filelist[:2])
```